# Why did "cpanm Email::Sender::Simple" change directory permissions for other modules, breaking bugzilla?

Tags: perl, cpan

So I was working on a small Perl project and needed the Email::Sender::Simple module. I installed it, for some reason, via cpanm instead of cpan like I usually do:

```
cpanm Email::Sender::Simple
```

After installing the module, I checked my Bugzilla installation, and found that it was totally broken. The bugzilla homepage was just reporting an error. It wasn't able to find modules like Data::OptList, which wasn't on the @INC path.

I determined the problem was that the file permissions in /usr/local/share/perl/5.8.8 had been changed, with many directories now having permissions like this:

```
drwx------ 4 root root
```

That is, only root was allowed to *look* in the directory. Those directories need to be readable by my "www-data" user so that Bugzilla can find and use modules such as Data::OptList.

Bugzilla has a checksetup.pl script which often fixes file permission problems, but it did not fix or detect this problem.

I was able to get things working again via:

```
find /usr/local/share/perl/5.8.8 -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;
```

After doing that, I'm back up and running. But I'm worried that other permissions might have been changed. And I can't understand why cpanm would be so bold, reconfiguring my file permissions.

Does anyone understand why cpanm would have altered permissions in /usr/local/share/perl/5.8.8 ? Might it have changed other things? Is there a way to prevent this from happening again? Is the "cpanm" command somehow different from "cpan" ?

Answer (score 0):

Unlikely story :) http://search.cpan.org/grep?cpanid=MIYAGAWA&release=App-cpanminus-1.5007&string=chmod&i=1&n=1&C=0

Comment: So, I think you are saying "cpanminus never invokes chmod, except to set execute permissions on itself"  "Therefore it can't have caused the problem" .... but perhaps it invoked something else which did? Perhaps a makefile of one of the dependent packages? I'm not trying to harsh on cpanm .. it is almost certainly doing its job :) I'm just pretty confident I didn't do anything else which would have caused the permissions change ...